# ChatBot with conditional response flow - Rasa Open Source

Tags: chatbot, rasa

I'm working on a Rasa (Open Source) project, I need to represent the diagram flow in a chatbot.

The main problem is following the conditional flow as the user can say yes or no and modify the flow of the conversation.

I would like to know how I could build a chatbot that contemplates all the possibilities represented in the diagram and the others that are outside it, using Rasa.

In other words, a chatbot that responds to the user according to his previous response.
Please.

[flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L1pk.png)

A "solution" I found was to create a story for each possible path, but it is "unfeasible" due to the number of stories. (there are 9 other diagrams like this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the flow and how you can map your designed diagrams into Rasa, you try to use one universal `story/rule` to make your structure more modular. You can find parts of the flow in your diagram that are being repeated on the other ones also and create your `story/rule`(s) out of them to be used in different flows. Rasa also supports `checkpoint`, which let you manage your stories in a more restrictive way.

For getting users' responses and acting accordingly, you need to deploy Rasa `forms` and `action` in your `story/rule`(s) for extracting those 'entities` you want to get from users and manipulate them.